# Accessing SVN repository from CCNet (CruiseControl.net) using an Active Directory user

Tags: svn, authentication, active-directory, cruisecontrol.net

I have CCNet setup to talk to our SVN repository, which has it's ACLs setup using Active Directory groups. This is working fine, except I'm not happy with having the user name and password of the AD user stored in plain text on the CCNet instance.

Is there a way to either encrypt the AD username/password, or get the CCNet service (I've tried running the service as the user and removing the the username/password section of the CCNet/SVN config) to use a domain account outside of the standard config?

Comment: Wow no answer for this after nearly a year?

Answer (score 5):

On the server that will run ccnet, use SVN from the command line to do something that requires authentication. That will cache your credentials using Windows.

Then run the service as the user and use <authCaching>Always</authCaching> in the config file.

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <authCaching>Always</authCaching>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: I never got a chance to test this as I'd already finished the contract I was working on when this solution was provided. This answer has quite a few upvotes, which would suggest that it's a working solution, can anyone confirm? I'll mark as answered shortly.